# nothing is being update after the execution of cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am doing this check_Clicked procedure to update a ListView but the update doesn't seems to works after the exec of cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    When I am debugging I can see the keyId value which is the proper Id in my table but for a unknow reason it didn't do the update.  Any hints why ?    Thanks

```
protected void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int keyId = 0;

    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {
       CheckBox MyCheckBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("MyCheckBox");
       if (MyCheckBox.Checked)
       {
          keyId = Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Value); 
       }
    }

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
       ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    //======= Insert Query.
    string cmdText = "UPDATE Doctor SET doctorName=@doctorName,dateApt=@dateApt,
       hrApt=@hrApt,clientname=@clientName WHERE apointmentId=@apointementId";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientName", Convert.ToString(Session["nom"]));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isAvailable", "False");

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apointementId", keyId);

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    ListApointement();
}

private void ListApointement()
{
   using (ListApointementDataContext db = new ListApointementDataContext())
   {
      var aptItems = from ListApointement in db.ListApointement select ListApointement;
      ListView1.DataSourceID = null;
      ListView1.DataSource = aptItems;
      ListView1.DataBind();
   };
}
```

Comment: Go into debug and paste the SQL, does it work there?

Comment: `aptItems` vs `rdvItems`?

Comment: Looks like alot of missing parameters to me...

Comment: I changes the error.  It should be aptItems and not rdvItems sorry.

Comment: Can you explain how to see the SQL code I am using VS 2013 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query, as it is now, looks like this:

```
string cmdText = "UPDATE Doctor SET doctorName=@doctorName,dateApt=@dateApt,
   hrApt=@hrApt,clientname=@clientName WHERE apointmentId=@apointementId";
```

It looks to me like you are including a parameter you aren't using in your query:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isAvailable", "False");
// You aren't passing this in your query but have it listed as a parameter...
```

And have parameters referenced in your query that you aren't using:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doctorName", // @doctorName type needs to go here);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateApt", // @dateApt type needs to go here);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hrApt", // @hrApt type needs to go here);
```

Comment: How come no error is generated by the sql ?  I added the missing column.   string cmdText = "UPDATE Doctor SET doctorName=@doctorName,dateApt=@dateApt,
                 hrApt=@hrApt,clientname=@clientName,isAvailable=@isAvailable WHERE apointmentId=@apointementId";

Comment: but no more success the database is still not updated

Comment: Can you explain me how to see the sql code generated in the back using Visual Studio 2013 ?

Comment: @user3127986 - I am not sure what you mean.  I do think you need to update your initial question with the code you said you have added above.  In some cases, the order you are passing the parameters is important too; like in the case of an `OleDbCommand`.